# overwrite all files from one folder to another folder with gulp

Tags: gulp

I already have my method that compresses the content of the files with gulp-minify-css in a temporary folder which I hope to later delete with gulp if possible but I don't see how to replace the files first, I have:

```js
var revReplace = require('gulp-rev-replace');  // -> this folder is not recognized

gulp.task('revrep', () => {
  return gulp.src('app/Styles/CssArqMincss')        
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/Content/CSSArq/'));
})
```

and how can I later delete the folder `/Styles/CssArqMincss`?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To delete files from folder location, you can use this task and adapt it.

```
const { src, task } = require( 'gulp' );
const clean = require("gulp-clean");
const logger = require('node-color-log');

function cleanFolderTask() {
    const yourPathRoot = "pathToYourFolder"; //I would recommend using config file to store paths, such as : config.path.artifact.root;
    logger.color('yellow').log(`Cleaning ${yourPathRoot}`);

    return src(yourPathRoot ,{allowEmpty: true},{read: false}).pipe(clean({force:true}));
};

const cleanFolderTask= task('clean:folder', cleanFolderTask);
exports.cleanFolderTask= cleanFolderTask;
```

To copy from one folder to another one, I would also use the previous task to first clean the destination and then :

```
const { src, dest, task } = require( 'gulp');
const logger = require('node-color-log');

function copyFilesTask(callback) {
    let filesLoc = "path/to/your/files"; 
    let filesDest = "path/to/destination"; // I would recommend using config file to store paths, such as : config.path.artifact.files and config.path.solution.files;

    logger.color('yellow').log(`Copy ${filesDest }`);

    src(`${filesLoc}/**/*`)
        .pipe(dest(filesDest), 
        callback());
};

const copyFiles = task('copy:files', copyFilesTask);
exports.copyFiles = copyFiles;
```